# Query about border types when using cv2.GaussianBlur

Tags: python, opencv

BORDER_REFLECT_101 is supposed to be this way for the border values when using padding: gfedcb|abcdefgh|gfedcba

Graphically it should be this way (upper left border of the image):

[image]

But what about those x's in the red square? How their values are decided? Thanks

---

The illustration below represents the upper left part of an image. If I wanted to do Gaussian Blur to this image using a 3x3 kernel, pixels (each one represented by an x) would be added. For the computation of the value of the output on the position occupied by 4 (inside the blue square) in the original image, the values of the "x" pixels inside this blue square will be needed. Now, if borderType = cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101 I understand what values they are. But I don't get what happens if borderType=cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED

[image]

Comment: The red part is a copy of the bottom right 3x3 pixels, flipped around both X and Y axis.
That is,`3,5,4 ; 8,7,5 ; 7,6,3` Easy to try with `copyMakeBorder`.

Comment: @DanMašek by the way, do you know how BORDER_ISOLATED works? Description says "do not look outside of ROI" and I don't get it because when using Gaussian Blur you need the values created by padding (the sum of the values of your gaussian kernel is equal to one, so you are supposed to use all the values of the padded image below the kernel)

Comment: See the *Note* in the [docs of `copyMakeBorder`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36).

Comment: I don't get it. How can the convolution (using Gaussian Blur) can be done without taking in account the values of pixels added by padding?

Comment: No, that's not what it means. What you can do with `cv::Mat` instances, and with numpy arrays as well, is create new `Mat`/array which acts as a view to a smaller "region of interest" (ROI) of that source image. It isn't a copy, it still uses the same underlying data, so if you modify it, you also modify the original image -- it's just smaller. (For example, you could create a view of just that red square in your example image). Now, if you try to apply `copyMakeBorder` (which is what GaussingBlur does before it does the convolution) to such an image, it will by default try to use ...

Comment: ... the surrounding pixels from the bigger source image (unless there aren't any due to the ROI being next to an edge). The `ISOLATED` flag suppresses this behaviour, and synthesize all the pixel values as if it was not a ROI. The flag is meant to be ORed with another flag specifying the mode, it acts as a modifier.

Comment: Just a note -- it might not be actually doing the `copyMakeBorder`, but rather `borderInterpolate` (to avoid the copy), but the idea is the same. Feel free to read the source code to figure out what exactly is going on there.

Comment: @DanMašek bro I get yout point but what would happen in the example below (see my own answer)

Comment: I'll write up some examples for you tomorrow to illustrate this better. It's getting a bit late here now.

Comment: @DanMašek Maybe the values of the gaussian kernel above 4 5; 5 3 (see the blue square) get scalated to sum 1 when using cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED, that way the convolution is done with just 4 values of the kernel?

Comment: No. I've played with it a bit, and it turns out in Python cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED is irrelevant, as OpenCV doesn't recognise numpy array views as ROIs.

Comment: Keep in ind that the flag is not meant to be used on itself, but ORed with another flag -- it's a modifier. If you use it on its own, it's the same as if you used `cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT`, most likely with default value for the constant which is 0.